# fetch_feed showing only first item

Tags: rss, feed

I'm trying to import a feed from a WordPress site to another using `fetch_feed()`.
All is good except for the fact I can get only the first item of the feed.

### Here's the code I'm using

```
add_shortcode('custom_feed','feed2');
 function feed2(){
    $rss = fetch_feed( 'http://blog.sugarpulp.it/feed/' );
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, 3 );
    foreach ( $rss_items as $item) {
        $title      = $item->get_title();
        return $title;
    }
 }
```

Hope can help me out. This thing is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is from this line `return $title;` inside the `foreach` loop.

Try something like this instead:

```
add_shortcode('custom_feed','feed2');
 function feed2(){
    $rss = fetch_feed( 'http://blog.sugarpulp.it/feed/' );
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, 3 );
    $out = array();
    foreach ( $rss_items as $item) {
        $out[] = $item->get_title();
    }
    return join( ' ', $out );
 }
```

using only a single `return` after the loop.

From the PHP manual on `return` :

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
>   the value of the function call.

You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php).